# WPF Textbox Value Doesn't Include Decimal Digit 0

Tags: wpf, textbox, decimal, mask

In the KeyUp event of a WPF textbox, the value of textBox.Text is correct, unless the user enters a 0. For example, if the user enters 5.88, the textBox.Text value is "5.88". If the user enters 5.80, the textBox.Text value is "5.8" (the 0 is dropped). We're only allowing the user to enter one decimal digit, so, if they enter 5.80, we want to trim the 0. The problem is that we can't, because the code that does the trimming, only sees "5.8". When the operation is done, "5.80" still appears in the textbox for the user to see.

Any idea why this would happen?

Note: There is a converter applied to the textbox, but the KeyUp event sets the value to textBox.Text. So, if the converter produces 5.8, the textBox.Text value gets set to "5.8".

Edit: Here is some of the code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:StringToBooleanConverter x:Key="stringToBooleanConverter" />
    <converters:SecondsToMinutesConverter x:Key="secondsToMinutesConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox Text="{Binding ApplyTimeInSeconds, Converter={StaticResource secondsToMinutesConverter},
TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"                                                         
vab:Validate.BindingForProperty="Text"
Name="ApplyTimeTextBox"
KeyUp="ApplyTimeTextBox_KeyUp"
Width="75" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=applyTimeCheckbox, Path=IsChecked}"/>



private void ApplyTimeTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewUtility.RemoveExtraDecimalDigits(sender as TextBox, 1);
    }

    // We don't want to allow more than one decimal position. So, if the user types 4.38, remove the 8. Or change 4.389 to 4.3.
    internal static void RemoveExtraDecimalDigits(TextBox textBox, int numberOfDecimalDigitsAllowed)
    {
        if (!textBox.Text.Contains(".")) { return; }

        string originalText = textBox.Text;

        textBox.Text = GetValueWithCorrectPrecision(textBox.Text, numberOfDecimalDigitsAllowed);

        // If the text changed, move the cursor to the end. If there was no change to make, or maybe the user hit the
        // HOME key, no reason to move the cursor.
        if (textBox.Text != originalText)
        {
            MoveCursorToEnd(textBox);
        }
    }

    private static string GetValueWithCorrectPrecision(string textValue, int numberOfDecimalDigitsAllowed)
    {
        int indexOfDecimalPoint = textValue.IndexOf('.');

        string[] numberSection = textValue.Split('.');

        if (numberSection[1].Length > numberOfDecimalDigitsAllowed)
        {
            // Keep the decimal point and the desired number of decimal digits (precision)
            return textValue.Remove(indexOfDecimalPoint + numberOfDecimalDigitsAllowed + 1);
        }

        return textValue;
    }

    private static void MoveCursorToEnd(TextBox textBox)
    {
        textBox.Select(textBox.Text.Length, 0);  // Keep cursor at end of text box
    }
```

And here is the converter:

```
public class SecondsToMinutesConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a value from the source (domain object/view model) to the target (WPF control).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value produced by the binding source.</param>
    /// <param name="targetType">The type of the binding target property.</param>
    /// <param name="parameter">The converter parameter to use.</param>
    /// <param name="culture">The culture to use in the converter.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A converted value. If the method returns null, the valid null value is used.
    /// </returns>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value == null) { return null; }

        decimal bindingSourceValueAsDecimal = System.Convert.ToDecimal(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        return Decimal.Round(bindingSourceValueAsDecimal / 60, 2);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a value from the target (WPF control) to the source (domain object/view model).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value that is produced by the binding target.</param>
    /// <param name="targetType">The type to convert to.</param>
    /// <param name="parameter">The converter parameter to use.</param>
    /// <param name="culture">The culture to use in the converter.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A converted value. If the method returns null, the valid null value is used.
    /// </returns>
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value == null) { return null; }

        decimal bindingTargetValueAsDecimal;

        if(Decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), out bindingTargetValueAsDecimal) == false) { return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue; }

        return Math.Round(bindingTargetValueAsDecimal * 60, 2);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a little of your code here? What's going on in the KeyUp event? Are you doing anything with the value of Text before checking it or is the Text property literally dropping the zero?

Comment: The TextBox doesn't care about decimals, digits, or anything of the like. It treats everything as text. Something in your code is causing this behavior; give it a thorough walk-through.

Comment: I included some of the code above. Hope it helps.

Comment: We have no idea how the converter is being used until we see your binding on the `TextBox` and enough of the object it's binding to for a full picture of what's going on. Basically, you need to give enough code that we can actually reproduce the behavior on our own.

Comment: Good point. XAML added above.

Answer (score 0):

In effect, I tried to reproduced the behavior, without the converter (as I don't know how it's bound), and if I undertand well the expected behavior, It works well...

When I enter 5.88, the last digit is erased (I get 5.8).
When I enter 5.80, the last digit is also erased (I get 5.8).

Could you be more specific on what you can't do ?
Have you tried without any converter ? Or could you update your code with the XAML using the converter ?

Comment: I just included the entire converter class, and the XAML to include it in Window.Resources.The bottom line is that the code won't remove the second decimal digit if it's a 0. And I have a feeling that's because the converter removes it as part of returning a decimal type.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue... Still missing some part of the XAML code : 
- what is `{Binding ApplyTimeInSeconds`, what is your DataContext ?
- `TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}` I can't have this one
- `Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"` I don't have the style
- `{Binding ElementName=applyTimeCheckbox` what's that ?
Your feeling is good (when I type 3.80m in a decimal value variable, I get 3.8 in the debugger watcher)...
But as I can't come in the Converter with the debugger I can't find out where is the issue exactly.
Could you please provide a working code ? (please test)

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you to use PreviewKeyUp or PreviewTextInput rather than the KeyUp event.

As an alternative you might want to mask your textbox, either
1. by using a [MaskedTextBox](http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2008/12/17/wpf-masked-textbox.aspx), OR
2. by [modifying the behaviour of textbox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MaskableTextBox.aspx) by using an attached property.

In case of 2, you might want to modify the ValidateValue function for your requirement.